# How long will it take to pay off a mortgage?

Tags: finance

If a mortgage principal is `$200,000`, interest rate is `3.50%` and the payment is `$900` a month.  Is there an equation to find how many payments it would take to pay off the loan?

#### Edit 1

I have tried to solve `n` and have not been able too.  So I tried just solving `P` to see if your equation comes out with a `1000` and it does not appear to.

I wrote your equation in Python to solve `P` as shown below.  Maybe you can tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
P=1000
R=50
i=0.04
n=20
print (1-(1+i/12)**n)/(i/12)*R
#The above prints out -1032.30906873
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In Edit 1, you wrote `(1+0.04/12)**n` for the formula $(1+i)^{-n}.$ The part where you write `0.04/12` is OK, because the $i$ in $(1+i)^{-n}$ is the interest per payment period (which is once a month in your example). But notice the minus sign in the exponent of $(1+i)^{-n}$: you should have written `**(-n)` instead of `**n`.

Comment: My fault.  So now if I do `print (1-(1+i/12)**-n)/(i/12)*R` it comes out to `965.839416178`.  The problem is I don't know how to solve `n`. I tried a few different ways using `Logarithm` but its jut not working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $P=(\frac{1-(1+i)^{-n}}{i})R$. R is how much you pay per period (\$ 900), P is your principal (\$ 200000), and i is your interest rate per period ($\frac{0.035}{12}$). Now solve for n to compute how many months it takes to pay this mortgage off.

Comment: Ok, how do I solve `n` above?  Can you by any chance give me an example?

Comment: Say you wanted to know how long it would take to pay off a loan of $\$ 1000$ at an interest rate of 4% compounded monthly paying $\$ 50$ monthly. Plugging into the equation you have that $$1000=\frac{1-(1+\frac{0.04}{12})^{-n}}{\frac{0.04}{12}}*(50).$$ Solving for $n:$

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778429/extra-payment-mortgage-calculator).  So someone can mark this as a duplicate.

Anyway, thank you @Sean Nemetz for trying to help.